# Schade vs traurig sein vs verstimmt sein

Tags: meaning, difference, phrase

Wir haben gestern diskutiert, welcher der drei Ausdrücke in einem Brief am wenigsten den Eindruck erweckt, dass man einen Vorwurf macht. Vielleicht kann uns ein(e) Muttersprachler(in) weiterhelfen

> Ach schade, ...
>
> Ich bin etwas verstimmt, ...
>
> Ich bin etwas traurig, ...

... dass es nicht geklappt hat

Oder gibt es noch eine bessere Alternative?

Comment: Das hängt viel mehr von der Betonung und Mimik ab, als von dem Ausdruck an sich.

Comment: Ich bin voll bei dir, aber in einem Brief?

Comment: Meine persönliche Meinung (als Muttersprachler) wäre "Schade, dass Du nicht kommen kannst!".

Comment: Worauf bezieht sich "nicht klappen"?

Comment: Man müsste viel mehr Kontextwissen haben, um das zu beantworten, inklusive bisherigem Briefverkehr und üblichem Ausdruck und Einblick in das Vertrautheitsverhältnis zwischen den Parteien. Wenn etwas zu steif oder zu salopp formuliert wird, wirkt es unauthentisch, wäre bei einem anderen Adressaten aber vielleicht genau richtig.

Comment: @userunknown ich habe leider nicht so viele Einzelheiten. Das war eine Online-Diskussion. Wir haben nach einer Übersetzung gesucht. Das Wort auf Russisch klingt eher neutral. Google hat hierfür 'verärgert' vorgeschlagen, was für mich weniger neutral klingt. Enttäuscht war ein anderer Vorschlag. Und dann haben wir noch das Wort 'verstimmt' gesehen. Das Wort habe ich gestern zum ersten Mal überhaupt gehört

Comment: @MurVotema: Wenn Du einem ungelernten Arbeiter schreibst "ich war verstimmt" wird er Dich wahrscheinlich für versnobt halten. Generell sind Ich-Botschaften (ich fühle mich soundso) geeignet, Vorwürfe zu vermeiden - da bin ich anderer Ansicht als Ralf Joerres. Die Frage ist aber, welche Stimmung man hatte (Trauer, Ärger, Enttäuschung, ...). Das können wir nicht wissen - nicht mal erahnen. Man kann all diese Stimmungen abmildern ("Wir waren ein wenig verstimmt/traurig/enttäuscht ...").

Comment: Eine weitere Variante ist: *es ist bedauerlich, dass...*. Wie schon mehrere Vorredner sagten, ist deutlich mehr Kontext nötig, um zu beurteilen, was das passendste ist.

Answer (score 1):

*Verstimmt* ist für mich klar vorwurfsvoll, vergleichbar 'sauer', nur etwas dezenter ausgedrückt. *Traurig* betont ebenfalls eine persönliche emotionale Reaktion: *Und du, du hast mich traurig gemacht*. Nicht vorwurfsvoll wäre

> Da hast du echt was verpasst. Wir fanden es alle so schade, dass du nicht dabei warst.

Und wenn das zu lang bzw. unpassend ist:

> Einfach schade. Dann vielleicht beim nächsten Mal

oder

> Man soll ja nicht über verschüttete Milch weinen, aber schade war's doch.

Wenn etwas nicht klappt, stellt sich wohl immer die Frage der Verantwortlichkeit. Will man den anderen komplett freisprechen, kann man immer auch auf

> C'est la vie

oder ähnliches zurückgreifen.

Comment: "Man soll ja nicht über verschüttete Milch weinen, aber schade war's doch" empfinde ich geradezu als vorwurfsvoll (je nachdem, wer "die Milch verschüttet hat")...

Comment: @Nico: Man kann das vielleicht so auffassen, je nach Kontext. Ich hab's immer so verstanden: Es ist ein Bagatellschaden, mit dem man sich nicht lange aufhalten und den man nicht dramatisieren soll, also '_wir wollen jetzt keine große Geschichte draus machen_' bzw. '_sowas kann doch immer mal passieren_'. Denn niemand schüttet ja Milch mutwillig aus, um dann nachher darüber zu weinen. Das Verschütten war also ungewollt, und Pannen passieren nun mal jedem. Für mich steht 'der Schaden ist zu gering, um sich selbst oder anderen Vorwürfe zu machen' bei dieser Redewendung im Vordergrund.

Comment: Interessant! Jeder empfindet es wahrscheinlich anders. Bei mir evoziert "verschütten" Fahrlässigkeit...

Comment: Kann ich nachvollziehen. Ist das Weinen dann bei Dir ein Weinen von Krokodilstränen?

Comment: Nee, kann auch ehrlich gemeint sein.

Comment: Und nach meinem Empfinden wiederum ist die dominante Bedeutung des Spruchs von der verschütteten Milch das "*ist nicht mehr zu ändern*"